# Conflicts with injected ember.js in contentscript's chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ember.js, ember-router

I'm creating a chrome extension and I want to use ember.js inside. I just create a very basic one which is working fine with most of websites but not with websites like gmail or feedly. With those websites, I get errors like :

> Assertion failed: The route my was not found ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
>   (anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364 Ember.assert
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:52 Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend._doTransition
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:26488 Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend.handleURL
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:26331
>   Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend.startRouting
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:26312
>   Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.startRouting
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:30234
>   Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.didBecomeReady
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:30192 DeferredActionQueues.flush
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4746 Backburner.end ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4830
>   Backburner.run ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4869 Ember.run
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:5200 (anonymous function)
>   ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:29937 jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
>   jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
>   jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433 completed

Have you an idea how to solve that?
Content script run isolated (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment); it looks to be the routing routine of ember.js which catch all events but I'm not skilled enough to understand what happend.

my manifest.json :

```
{
  "name": "Ember module test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made ;)",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "cookies", "\u003Call_urls\u003E", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "pageCapture" ],
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jquery-1.9.1.js", "handlebars-1.0.0.js", "ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js", "contentScript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ]

}
```

My contentScript.js:

```
var wrapperHTML = '                      <script type=\"text/x-handlebars\">    <h2>Title</h2>    {{outlet}}  </script>  <script type=\"text/x-handlebars\" data-template-name=\"index\">    {{#each item in model}}      <li>{{item}}</li>    {{/each}}    </ul>  </script>';

function initWrapperHTML() {
        var newNode = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(newNode);
        newNode.innerHTML += wrapperHTML;
}
initWrapperHTML();

AppEmber = Ember.Application.create();

AppEmber.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

AppEmber.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'emberorange'];
  }
});
```

To reproduce my problem, create a folder with the 2 files bellow and add ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js, handlebars-1.0.0.js and jquery-1.9.1.js in it and in chrome://extensions add the folder with "Load unpack extension..."

Thank you

Comment: In some cases routing may be an issue..when there is router of its own, this kind of error may arise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Javascript execution environment of a content script is isolated from that of the webpage, they share the same document. In particular they share the current URL.

By default, `ember.js` uses the hash part of the URL to establish which application route it should follow.

From the error message you posted it seems you were visiting this URL: `http://cloud.feedly.com/#my`, that's why you got the error 'The route my was not found'.

Depending on you application, you may try disabling the interaction between the router and the URL, as described here: [Specifying the URL Type](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/).

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```